# plot_covariate_groups in lifiline gives NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, survival-analysis, cox-regression, lifelines

I am running survival cox regression with time-varying covariates :

```
from lifelines import CoxTimeVaryingFitter

ctv = CoxTimeVaryingFitter(penalizer=0.1)
ctv.fit(train_long, id_col="ID", event_col="daysInDeliquency", start_col="start", stop_col="stop", show_progress=True, formula="REER+inflation")
```

I want to see the partial effect of my variable on survival, for example, variable  `REER` and I am running the code:
`ctv.plot_covariate_groups(covariates='REER'`)
But this give me error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not define
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to this [lifelines documentation](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html)
'plot_covariate_groups' is no longer used and been renamed to 'plot_partial_effects_on_outcome'.
Try to use it. It worked for me.